# Can't pass a string to my class function

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a class with this function:

```
void Render(SDL_Surface *source,SDL_Surface *destination,string img)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = m_x;
    offset.y = m_y;
    source = IMG_Load(img);
    offset.w = source->w;
    offset.h = source->h;    
}
```

For some reason though even with `include <string>` at the top of the header file it won't allow it. I get:

```
Identifier, "string" is undefined.
```

Im passing the data like this on my main file:

```
btn_quit.Render(menu,screen,"button.png");
```

When i execute i get :

```
'Button::Render' : function does not take 3 arguments
```

But this site says `string` is the correct syntax for the data type (at the bottom): http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Can some one explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you specify the namespace anywhere?

Comment: on my main cpp file yes is that the correct place?

Comment: Try writing `std::string` anyway.

Comment: Ok that sorta worked but then for IMG_Load it says `'IMG_Load' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'`

Comment: then you use IMG_Load(img.c_str());

Comment: class names start with a capital letter. Try changing 'string' to 'String'

Comment: @Ahmad-San: In C++, the conventional style (as used in the Standard and many other examples) is to not use capital letters except for macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may suggest you change Render function to below:

```
void Render(SDL_Surface *source,SDL_Surface *destination,const std::string& img)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = m_x;
    offset.y = m_y;
    source = IMG_Load(img.c_str());
    offset.w = source->w;
    offset.h = source->h;    
}
```

1. use std::string instead of string
2. pass img reference instead of passing by value
3. change from IMG_Load(img); to IMG_Load(img.c_str());

Comment: May i ask the difference between using string& and just string normal ? In terms of both performance and any other technical issue i might come accross ?

Comment: 'string img' will make a copy of the whole string into the function but string&img will only copy the address of the string, so pass by reference is faster. as you don't want Render to modify value of img, add const

Comment: Ah so basically it saves memory?

Comment: did you update your function declaration to the same as definition?

Comment: I had forgot to add "const" i fixed that now :) thanks!! Will tick your answer.